# MYSQL How to get rows from highest rank to highest-range

Tags: mysql

I have a table `agents`:

```
ID rank
1  300
2  302
3  304
4  305<--the highest number
5  301
6  260
7  301
...
```

Do you know how to get all top rows from the highest rank (4=>305) to row with rank = highest_rank-*range*? *Range* is user defined (eg. = 3). So in this example it will be rows with rank 305 to 302 (IDs: 2, 3, 4).
Is there a better way than:

```
SELECT ID FROM `agents` WHERE rank >= (SELECT rank FROM `agents` ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 1)-3
```

?

Comment: why not jus this? `select * from table order by rank desc limit 3`

Comment: Sorry, I add that I would prefer other method because in both queries in WHERE I have to use more conditions...

Comment: @Strawberry also Vijaykumar Hadalgi Please read once again, it's not top 3 rows, you dont know how many rows it will be. Its from top to top-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood you correctly...

```
 CREATE TABLE agents
 (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,rank INT NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO agents VALUES
 (1  ,300),
 (2  ,302),
 (3  ,304),
 (4  ,305),
 (5  ,301),
 (6  ,260),
 (7  ,301);

 SELECT x.*
   FROM agents x
   JOIN (SELECT MAX(rank) max_rank FROM agents) y
     ON y.max_rank-3 <= x.rank;
 +----+------+
 | ID | rank |
 +----+------+
 |  2 |  302 |
 |  3 |  304 |
 |  4 |  305 |
 +----+------+
```

An alternative answer, provided by BrokenHeart has been deleted. But it was a good answer, so I'm including it below...

```
 SELECT id, rank FROM `agents` 
 where rank >= ((select MAX(rank) FROM `agents`)-13);
```

Comment: Great. Can you tell me if counting lowest bound (max-range) will be faster with JOIN?

Comment: Comparing to Broken Heart's MAX, is it faster? :)

Comment: Thanks Strawberry, this table will be much bigger. I'll implement JOIN  for now and add todo

Comment: On such a tiny dataset, it couldn't make any difference. Try it again when your dataset gets 10,000 times larger. But even then, with an index on rank, performance should be fine and the difference negligible.

Comment: Not sure why the other answer was removed. It is a good solution - and may yet prove faster!!!

Comment: Can you tell me on thing more? In this table I have also column `period` INT. I have to add in query 'WHERE period = 1 or 2 etc.' Where I should add this? Is it enough to add this at the end?

Comment: I didn't remove it :/

Comment: fck, I have to add `WHERE period = INT` in JOIN otherwise the max value is wrong :/ so WHERE will be doubled

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7382c/4/0 can you check if is it possible not to use double WHERE?

Comment: So you only want to select one period at a time?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7382c/11 :-) If you want, you can adapt this solution to return ALL periods in one go.

Comment: No. Merely top 2% this quarter ;-)

Comment: You should be between max and max minus range, for range=0 :D